# ¿Es posible generar un SSL para que mi página web sea segura?

Tags: wordpress, web, seguridad, ssl, openssl

Hay muchos sitios que venden certificados SSL, ¿es posible generar nuestro propio certificado SSL para una página web de un comercio? ¿se podría hacer con openssl de linux?¿o bien podriamos obtener uno gratis y después ampliar el periodo de caducidad (let's encrypt con un registro creo que para wordpress te da uno de periodo de 90 días?

Muchas gracias, chicos!

Comment: Supongo que por crear tu propio certificado SSL te refieres a uno que sea auto-firmado (self-signed). Poder hacerse, se puede, pero tendrás que verificarlo o los usuarios van a ver una página de aviso antes de entrar al sitio indicando que el sitio no pudo ser validado y que puede no ser de confianza.

Comment: Mirando online, parece que se puede auto-verificar con openssl, aunque parece que tendría que ser en otra máquina linux (enlaces: [`1`](https://gist.github.com/kyledrake/d7457a46a03d7408da31) y [`2`](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/216128468-OpenSSL-commands-to-check-and-verify-your-SSL-certificate-key-and-CSR)).

Comment: Una opción es https://letsencrypt.org/